# PHP: How to read N bytes from socket?

Tags: php, sockets, stream

I want to open socket and read first 6 bytes.

`$data = stream_socket_recvfrom($stream, 6);`

But if client send null byte, function read only first part of data and stops reading.

```
{0x51, 0x01, 0x00, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11}
```

And I get only `{0x51, 0x01}`

How to read all 6 bytes in this case?

Thank you

Comment: Can you use http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recv.php ?

Comment: how did you set up the stream? php doesn't use null terminators in strings, so there's no reason for it to stop at a null.

Comment: To create I use stream_socket_server() like there:
https://github.com/reactphp/socket/blob/master/src/Server.php

I use it class

Comment: @MarcB You are right. Problem was in C++ strlen function on client side. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, problem was not in PHP. Client on C++ incorrect calculate message length:

```
send(sock, chars, strlen(chars), 0);
```

And strlen of C++ breaks on null byte.